# Insert nofollow in a "Powered By" link, except in the homepage

Tags: functions, footer, nofollow

I want to insert the **nofollow** value in a "Powered by" link if the page is different than the homepage.

So I have written this:

```
function prefix_poweredby() {
    if ( is_front_page() ) {
        $html = '<a href="https://example.com" target="_blank">link</a>';
        echo $html;
    } else {
        $html = '<a href="https://example.com" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">link</a>';
        echo $html;
    }
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'prefix_poweredby');
```

It's working just fine, but I'm pretty sure that there are other more elegant ways to write this function and I would love if you could share with me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's any more elegant, but if you don't like duplicating the HTML code, you could do this:

```
function prefix_poweredby() {
    $html = '<a href="https://example.com"';
    if ( ! is_front_page() ) {
       $html .= ' rel="nofollow"';
    }
    $html .= ' target="_blank">link</a>';
    echo $html;
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'prefix_poweredby');
```